# Using Process Builder, can I convert an incoming lead to a Task or Event on a Contact

Tags: process-builder

I have leads coming in with a very specific Lead Source. Due to how the lead is created, I know that the lead email exists in SF on a Contact record.

I want to create a Task or Event (under Activities) on the Contact record, based on the email address of the lead.

Is this possible?

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Not possible using process builder, you'd have to use flow or apex to achieve this.

Comment: Process builder triggering an Autolaunched Flow or calling an Apex class to lookup the contact and add the Activity record under that contact.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to, but I recall you may only do this on update, not insert.

What you'll need to do is setup crtieria to grab your known "leads to convert."

Then, setup an autolaunched flow that is called by the Process Builder to do the following, which you will pass-in the Lead as a sObject variable:

1. Create Account record using information from Lead -- Save Account.Id to a variable named **myConvertedAccountId** for reference later
2. Create Contact record using infromation from Lead -- Set Contact.AccountId = your AccountId you created in step 1 and save the Contact.Id to a variable named **myConvertedContactId** for reference later
3. If you need an Opportunity created on lead conversion, follow the same process as illustrated in step 2.  You should have the AccountId and ContactId in your variable list.  Save Opportunity.Id to variable named **myConvertedOpportunityId** for reference later
4. Now, using the Assignment component, set values of the Lead to convert as follows

Lead.isConverted = TRUE

Lead.convertedAccountId = myConvertedAccountId

Lead.convertedContactId = myConvertedContactId

Lead.convertedOpportunityId - myConvertedOpportunityId

Lead.convertedDate = NOW()

Lead.status = "Converted"

Should this be an insert-only feature to convert a lead via API, then you can follow all steps above with a key difference --> Delete the lead that was loaded (save to an sObject variable FIRST!) and then insert as new with all the original infromation + the converted fields.

Comment: Having a bit of trouble getting this to work. The flow is updating the lead, and the debugger is showing that to be the case, but the leads remains unconverted. Were you able to get this to function as expected?